# Synchronously update several node.js applications deployed on the same server

Tags: node.js, server, updates

I'm wondering if it is possible to update synchronously several (let's say 10 or more) node.js applications deployed on the same server ?

How to update and restart all the node.js applications at the same time ?

Thank you for your help.

[EDIT]

Let's say each time one of my customers needs an "instance" of my node.js application, I create a new instance of it.

After 1 month, I want to update the node.js application for, let's say, my 10 customers (so 10 instances).

What would be the way to automate the process, not to have to automate one by one the 10 different instances ?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.. but maybe take a look into [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Comment: Please see my editing. Thanks.